# Pictures sliding up or down by mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Please see sites like

{links removed]

Inside the slider if you hover the mouse up or down the image inside the slider moves up or down.

Is it achieved through angular.js or node.js or javascript/jquery itself ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done by Galleria js, check out the documentation and examples here:

http://galleria.io/

And i think the theme that is being used there is the following:

http://galleria.io/themes/miniml/

It seems that when the image is bigger than the container it will do the effect that you are seeing.

Maybe if you read the documentation and the source of the js you can check how they do it. Probably it is done with translate and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

It is achieved through jquery use position absolute you can use translate3d and you just set on tag top in css